# mvc4 bundling strongly typed bundles

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, strong-typing, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

So MVC 4 introduces script and style bundling. Which allows for this:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mobile").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-*"));
```

then used in a razor view like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mobile")
```

My question is why do I have to type `"~/bundles/mobile"`? Is there a way get intellisence to have a strongly typed object to pick up on? Otherwise I have to go look it up to make sure I call it the same thing.

I would like to do something like this: (I know this won't compile this way, it's just an example)

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
    Bundle mobile = new Bundle("mobile");
    mobile.AddFile("w/e")
    bundles.Add(mobile);

//in page:
 @Scripts.Render(BundleConfig.mobile)
```

or something to that affect.

**Edit**: the answer so simple. As `@Hao Kung` points out `@Styles.Render` simply takes a url string path. I created a class to hold the pathes.

```
public class bundles
{
    #region Javascript
    public static string scripts = "~/bundles/scripts";
    ...
    #endregion

    #region CSS

    public static string css = "~/Content/css";
    public static string jqueryUi = "~/Content/themes/base/css";
    ...
    #endregion
}
```

in any page then you simply do

```
@Styles.Render(bundles.jqueryUi)
```

there you have it. A little extra effort on your part, but at least it's strongly typed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Render Scripts/Styles Render helpers are not limited to rendering references to bundles, they resolve any urls, so the only way for the helper to detect that you mean to reference a bundle, is by passing in the virtual path of the bundle.