# Why does this bundle not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I have an mvc style bundle configured.

It has two css files to include. Here is the bundle in question:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css", "~/Content/jasmine.css"));
```

There is literally no difference between these files.

Here is my usage of the bundle in my layout:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

Opening the chrome inspector I find this:

```
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But no jasmine.css.

What is the problem ? Why isn't my file included ?

**EDIT**

Here is the screenshot of the folder :

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the URL helper to choose a file??

Comment: protip and shameless plug: I had a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104879/mvc4-bundling-strongly-typed-bundles) about strongly typed bundles you may be interested in

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this occur when a file is missing or I specified the wrong path. Verify the path to `"~/Content/jasmine.css"`

Comment: Indeed, check that the file exists on disk. I just tried building an MVC4 app with the exact scenario that @Robo described and it works fine and I get both reference.

Comment: see vs solution explorer screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You might use an `.Include("~/ContentAddress")` per content or script, that you want to add to your bundle.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
.Include("~/Content/site.css")
.Include("~/Content/jasmine.css"));
```